# Is The Lord of the Flies set on a real island?

Tags: lord-of-the-flies, william-golding, setting

It is a well-known fact that the author of *Lord of the Flies* William Golding was an officer in the Royal Navy, and that some of the sights he saw inspired him to write *Lord of the Flies*.

The boys are stranded on an island. All we know about this island is that there are a mountain, trees and a lagoon.

The *Lord of the Flies* was also inspired by the book [The Coral Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Coral_Island).

Is the island that the boys get stranded on real? Perhaps Golding saw the island during his naval service, or maybe he set it on the same island as that in *The Coral Island*.

Answer (score 5):

The island is never named.

We get pretty close:

> “This is our island. It’s a good island. Until the grownups come to fetch
>   us we’ll have fun.”

However, the island is never named and we also don't know where in the world it takes place.  Though the book was based on *The Coral Island,* the island in question is just a generic island, which happens to be coral.  I don't think the island is important to the story, though.

I could find nothing in all my searches that indicates that the island was based on a real island, especially since it is so perfectly suited to Golding's needs (for example, the mountain, Castle Rock, the pools, and all the symbolism of the island throughout the novel.)

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the claim that there is no significance to the particular island, that it can be just any island, the demonic enchantment must be considered of fundamental importance, as well as the contrast to the utopian nobility portrayed in the book on which it was based and written to refute, "The Coral Island."

See: https://www.123helpme.com/essay/A-Comparsion-of-Coral-Island-and-Lord-305485 and https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/flies/quotes/setting/the-island/ for elaboration.

Comment: Please [edit] to include essential parts of the argument from those links. Link-only answers are subject to sudden breakage; we prefer answers to be self-contained